# Fluent UI DetailsList - Is there a way to add filters to each column

Tags: reactjs, office-fabric

I am using [Fluent UI DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist). My table looks like below:
[image]

I need filters below every column (text or drop-down) as shown below:
[image]

Please let me know if this is possible? Or maybe a way to display custom header (using html) ?

Comment: The link you provided includes a demo with filter functions I guess

Comment: I know that. I do not want a common search box but need a way to add filters under every column.

Comment: I'm working on the same implementation now, did you come up with a solution? There is an event to trigger a context menu, I'm just trying to work out the best/right way to put the ContextMenu inside the header...

Comment: No. Did not proceed after this.

Comment: 10-4, I'm on it... will report back when I get it working.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Solution below... slight variation from what you were looking for, but might be enough to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This actually turned out to be easier than I thought it'd be...

If you're ok with clicking the column header to reveal the choices (vs having the dropdown  directly under the title) then this can be achieved using the `ContextualMenu` component in conjunction with `DetailsList`. I got it working by tweaking from the variable row height example in the official docs: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/variablerowheights.

Add a ContextualMenu underneath your DetailsList:

```
<DetailsList
    items={items}
    columns={columns}
/>
{this.state.contextualMenuProps && <ContextualMenu {...this.state.contextualMenuProps} />}
```

Inside your column definition, set the `hasDropdown` action so the user gets a UI indicator that they can/should click the header, and call a contextMenu method (note I'm using `onColumnContextMenu` as well as `onColumnClick` so it doesn't matter if they left or right click the header:

```
{
    key: 'dept',
    name: 'Department',
    fieldName: 'dept',
    minWidth: 125,
    maxWidth: 200,
    onColumnContextMenu: (column, ev) => {
        this.onColumnContextMenu(column, ev);
    },
    onColumnClick: (ev, column) => {
        this.onColumnContextMenu(column, ev);
    },
    columnActionsMode: ColumnActionsMode.hasDropdown,
}
```

When the `onColumnContextMenu` method gets invoked, we need to build the context menu properties that will get consumed by the `ContextualMenu` component. Note the dismissal method as well, which clears out the state so the menu is hidden.

```
private onContextualMenuDismissed = (): void => {
    this.setState({
        contextualMenuProps: undefined,
    });
}

private onColumnContextMenu = (column: IColumn, ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    if (column.columnActionsMode !== ColumnActionsMode.disabled) {
        this.setState({
            contextualMenuProps: this.getContextualMenuProps(ev, column),
        });
    }
};
```

Finally, inside of `getContextualMenuProps` you need to determine what the options should be for the user to click. In this example, I'm simply giving sort options (you'll need to add an `onClick` handler to actually do something when the user clicks the item), but I'll use the `column` to determine what those items should actually be and paint the filters into the items collection so the user can select one to filter.

```
private getContextualMenuProps = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, column: IColumn): IContextualMenuProps => {
    const items: IContextualMenuItem[] = [
        {
            key: 'aToZ',
            name: 'A to Z',
            iconProps: { iconName: 'SortUp' },
            canCheck: true,
            checked: column.isSorted && !column.isSortedDescending,
        },
        {
            key: 'zToA',
            name: 'Z to A',
            iconProps: { iconName: 'SortDown' },
            canCheck: true,
            checked: column.isSorted && column.isSortedDescending,
        }
    ];

    return {
        items: items,
        target: ev.currentTarget as HTMLElement,
        directionalHint: DirectionalHint.bottomLeftEdge,
        gapSpace: 10,
        isBeakVisible: true,
        onDismiss: this.onContextualMenuDismissed,
    }
}
```

Note the `target` on the `ContextualMenuProps` object, which is what tells the `ContextualMenu` where to lock itself onto (in this case, the column header that you clicked to instantiate the menu.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more how do you enter the html elements, like input tag in the context menu? Your example above does not explain how to accomplish that.

Comment: Burre, the IContextualMenuItem has an OnRender property. You can render whatever you like in there, like a TextField  and a Button to sert the filter

Comment: Follow up regarding this, where will I insert the part that adds a filter object on the contextual menu dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Detail list filter for each column without context menu -

https://codesandbox.io/s/rajesh-patil74-jzuiy?file=/src/DetailsList.CustomColumns.Example.tsx

For instance - Providing filter in text field associated with each column will apply filter on color column.